# How do I create an application launcher without coding?

Tags: unity, launcher

I want to create a launcher for an application that I just installed but whatever I searched was about creating a file with `.desktop` extension, but I need another way to make this without any coding or typing.

I found Arronax but it doesn't work for me. that's not launching the desired application. Arronax can make `.desktop` file visually by selecting needed parameters. Somebody suggest me something please.

Comment: You mean an application currently *without*  a launcher, right?

Comment: a sort of,  there is a .sh file when i do sh ./app.sh it's start the application and  it has a icon in launcher when it's open but i cant keep it in launcher.

Comment: You probably need to tell a bit more about the application, which is it? A `tkinter` application by any chance?

Comment: Hi Ehsan, did you read my question above?

Comment: hi, the application is Jetbrains PhpStorm. I can't pin this to the launcher when it's open.

Answer (score 9):

#### Outside sources

What you need is  `gnome-desktop-item-edit` program. Basically it does the same thing - it creates a `.desktop` file. Why ? Because launchers are `.desktop` files, just pinned to launcher. Nothing more than that. Windows shortcuts are `.lnk` files too by they way, they just don't show up as files with `.lnk` extension, but if you ever mounted a Windows hard drive - you'll know.

The `gnome-desktop-item-edit` command is still available if you install `gnome-panel` or `gnome-tweak-tool`.

Once you have it, you can use this command in terminal:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit --create-new ~/Desktop
```

#### Homebrew

I've actually written a small script  for that purpose before (because why not ? ). You can copy the code, save to file, and run whenever you want it. That simple !

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

FORM=$(zenity --forms \ --title="Simple shortcut maker" --text="Create new .desktop file" \
        --add-entry="Program Name" \
        --add-entry="Command or path to file" \
        --add-entry="Terminal app(true/false)" \
        --add-entry="Icon (path)") 

[ $? == 0 ] || exit 1

awk -F'|' -v home="$HOME" '{ 
    FILE = home"/Desktop/"$1".desktop"
        print "[Desktop Entry]" >> FILE
        print "Type=Application" >> FILE
        print "Name="$1 >> FILE
        print "Exec="$2 >> FILE
        print "Terminal="$3 >> FILE
        if ($4 !~ /^[ ]*$/)
            print "Icon="$4 >> FILE ;
    system("chmod 755 " FILE);

}' <<< "$FORM"
```

And that's how it looks:

[image]

You will have `.desktop` file in your Desktop folder, which you can later pin to launcher.

*Note:* the content about the gnome-desktop-item-edit is provided by [fossfreedom's original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/66918/295286), please upvote his good work !

Answer (score 8):

Assuming your application is a GUI application, currently without a launcher, there is a simple way to let [Unity create the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/questions/716471/what-happens-internally-when-i-click-lock-to-launcher-in-unity) for you in `~/.local/share/applications`, after which you can move it to anywhere you like.

1. Run the (GUI) application a single time from command line.
2. In the Launcher, right-click on the icon that appears, running the application, choose "lock to launcher"

   [image]
3. Navigate to `~/.local/share/applications`, there you'll find your new launcher, created by Unity. Even the arguments you ran it with are included in the launcher. Since it is not executable yet, it will be iconless.
4. Make it executable (right-click in nautilus > permissions (tab), now you can move it to anywhere you like and double- click to start the application.

**N.B.** The name of a launcher which is not executable (yet) might differ from the name you saw in the Unity Launcher. If you doubt, simply sort the files in `~/.local/share/applications` by modification date, the latest edited file is your newly created launcher.

Comment: I like this answer. not even need to write a single line of command. The only thing I need to do is to rename the launch.