# Install XMind on Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: software-installation, 19.04, xmind

After upgrading Ubuntu to 19.04 I saw that installing XMind does not work out of the box anymore. When trying to install `XMind 8` (more exactly [xmind-8-update8-linux.zip](https://www.xmind.net/xmind/downloads/xmind-8-update8-linux.zip)) via the `setup.sh` included, some dependencies are not available in the recent version of Ubuntu.

I found out that a possible workaround is to download and install these missing dependencies manually from the 18.10 repos before running the XMind setup:

- [libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/370057411/libicu60_60.2-6ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
- [libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/372800071/libjavascriptcoregtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb)
- [libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb](http://launchpadlibrarian.net/372800074/libwebkitgtk-1.0-0_2.4.11-4_amd64.deb)

But, is anyone aware of a nicer or native solution in Ubuntu 19.04? 
Or, otherwise, is there any danger / drawback using these packages from 18.10?

---

Just for convenience: This is the list of all the already known workarounds required to get XMind running on recent versions of Ubuntu (a script carrying out the whole installation and all the fixes can be found in the [Ubuntu Pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4JVdbn8Fk6/)):

- [set absolute paths in the XMind.ini](https://askubuntu.com/a/891108/978503),
- [explicitly use OpenJDK version 8](https://askubuntu.com/a/1106088/978503),
- [fix the laggy workflow](https://www.camratus.com/2017/04/24/fix-xmind-slow-lag-on-ubuntu-16-04/),
- [create a launcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/869857/978503), and
- make custom user settings work (see script).

Comment: Clarification: Xmind (xmind.net) is paid software and has their own support channel.

Answer (score 0):

There is no risk to using the three manually installed missing dependency .deb packages from Ubuntu 18.10 in Ubuntu 19.04, even though the Ubuntu 18.10 packages will not be updated by the Software Updater.

The xmind snap package of XMind 2020 can be installed from Ubuntu Software or from the terminal in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu with the following command:

```
sudo snap install xmind
```

XMind has a proprietary license, but the xmind snap package is free software. For now, there is no time limit for the trial version and you can get access to most the features of XMind 2020, but the trial version is only available for personal use as all the exported files will have a watermark of XMind trial mode.

Comment: Thank you very much. The snap package seems to be available only for the versions using annual licenses (currently called `XMind 2020`). The version with a fixed license (`XMind 8`) does not seem to be available via snap.