# Install XMind on Xubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: bash, xubuntu, java, eclipse

I tried to install xmind-8-update8-linux in Xubuntu 20.04.3 using the recommended bash file, which I found in [pastebin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4JVdbn8Fk6/).

Unfortunately this bash cannot help to launch Xmind but I got (An error has occurred, see the log file I added below:

```
    !SESSION 2021-10-09 21:27:02.139 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=R3.7.8.201807240049
java.version=11.0.11
java.vendor=Ubuntu
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -eclipse.keyring @user.home/.xmind/secure_storage_linux
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -data ../workspace -eclipse.keyring @user.home/.xmind/secure_storage_linux

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2021-10-09 21:27:02.623
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

I know XMind required Java 8 but I see in the first lines of the code Java 11. Do you think this is only the problem? In this case which is the recommended solution?

Comment: I found a related discussion of xmind on a 16.04 machine https://askubuntu.com/questions/869848/how-to-install-run-xmind-v-8-in-ubuntu-16-04  Check through the thread as there are several answers there hopefully one of them may help you.

Comment: I fixed after I checked and installed java 8. :-) !!