# 16.04 IntelliJ IDEA Desktop Entry not working

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, 16.04, intellij

I tried running "Create Desktop Entry" both from "Tools" in main menu and "Configure" from the splash screen. It shows

```
Desktop Entry Created
You may now exit IDEA and start it from the system menu (restart a session if a new entry seem not to appear).
```

but after closing IDEA (without manually locking the icon to launcher), the icon is also removed. I have deleted the desktop entry under `~/.local/share/applications` according to this thread [Stack Overflow: Intellij launcher doesn't work on unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424254/intellij-launcher-doesnt-work-on-unity)

Then I tried

```
chmod 777 /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop
```

and dragged it to launcher, which still doesn't work.

`JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` are both set up correctly.

Comment: what command should be run by the launcher?

Comment: Did you check after logging out and logging in again. Sometimes unity icon cache is updated after logging out.

Comment: Make backup `~/.config` folder `cp ~/.config ~/.config-backup` and delete  `rm -rf ~/.config` folder. After this make reboot.

Comment: May I ask, did you run the `bin/idea.sh` as root with `sudo` ? Because that does  create a root-owned `.desktop` file , and you can't drag those to the launcher

Comment: @Serg no I didn't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to fix this by myself.

1. Make sure JAVA_HOME is set correctly in the profile of your shell. For instance, I'm using zsh so I have to add `export JAVA_HOME=/.....` in `~/.zshrc`
2. If you specified any jar file to run as `javaagent` in `idea.vmoptions`, make sure to specify its full path name.
3. Simply create .desktop file from IDEA or manually and point `Exec` parameter to the full path of your `idea.sh` file. Then drag it to the launcher. Works fine.

Answer (score 17):

There is no option as of right now for automatic pinning of the `.desktop` file to the launcher of an application that was just installed. It does not just include IntelliJ but many other applications.

Technically speaking , there are [ways to append an icon to the list of icons on the launcher](https://askubuntu.com/a/761021/295286) , however most developers don't use it and leave that option up to the user. Hence you *have to* manually pin the Launcher icon. Otherwise, once the program exits - the icon disappears from launcher, which is the proper behavior of any app that is not on the list of the launcher favorites.

As for the `.desktop` file itself - it is created.

[image]

Checking only the `Create a desktop entry` option creates the file in `~/.local/share/applications/` folder, which is typically where the launcher entries for unknown or user-specific apps go.

To confirm that , I've ran this after installation:

```
$ ls ~/.local/share/applications | grep idea
jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop
```

Checking `For all users` option will create `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`,  since the `/usr/share/applications` directory is available globally to all users.

Either of these is what you want, and they can be pinned to the launcher simply by dragging them from file manager or dash to the launcher. **NOTE**: the `bin/idea.sh` must be ran as your regular user - otherwise if you run it as root, the `.desktop` file will be root owned, hence you cannot drag that to the launcher. If that's the case, you can always `sudo chown $USER:$USER /path/to/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop`

You can always copy either of those to Desktop if that's what you want, but `.desktop` files aren't literally supposed to be on the desktop.

As a last resort, you can always manually create a `.desktop` file.

In my example, that would be

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/bin/sh /home/xieerqi/intellij/idea-IC-145.597.3/bin/idea.sh
Name=Intellij
Icon=/home/xieerqi/intellij/idea-IC-145.597.3/bin/idea.png
```

Notice , that this is different [from the example in the link you provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424254/intellij-launcher-doesnt-work-on-unity) . The `#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open` is unnecessary and `Exec` line actually runs `/bin/sh` and the `idea.sh` as parameter to it. Note that this `.desktop` file needs to have executable permissions, otherwise you will receive a warning "Untrusted application"

Comment: I changed the content of the generated .desktop file as you said, dragged it to launcher, clicked on it, nothing happened.

Comment: Please add this: You need to remove this folder: `~/.local/share/JetBrains/ ` to open the Installation Wizard again.

Answer (score 2):

Let us create and install a new desktop file `idea.desktop` which is a `shortcut` file for `IntelliJ IDEA`.

`$ vi ~/idea.desktop`

Type the following in the shortcut file `idea.desktop` using the editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]                                                                 
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=IntelliJ IDEA
Comment=IntelliJ IDEA
Exec=/opt/idea/bin/idea.sh
Icon=/opt/idea/bin/idea.png
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
Type=Application
StartupWMClass=IntelliJ IDEA
```

Now, run the following command to install `idea.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications/` directory:

`$ sudo desktop-file-install idea.desktop`

> Never directly copy **shortcut** file into **/usr/share/applications/** directory. If there are any errors  in shortcut file such as **idea.desktop** who is going to catch them? That is why we install using above command rather than **cp** command.  Command **desktop-file-install** is capable of catching errors!

In order to complete this answer, let us create a `symlink` in `/usr/local/bin` directory:

```
$ cd /usr/local/bin/
$ sudo ln -s /opt/idea/bin/
```

Alternatively, as the `IntelliJ IDEA` executable binary is located under `/opt/idea/bin`, we can also add its parent directory to our `$PATH` so that we can launch the program without specifying the absolute path to the binary file.

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:/opt/idea/bin"
```

I had similar shortcut issues while installing Netbeans 10.0, please refer [After installation, Netbeans 10.0 won't run from Ubuntu 18.04 desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107364/after-installation-netbeans-10-0-wont-run-from-ubuntu-18-04-desktop)

Answer (score 1):

simply u can:

1. run ./idea.sh again from terminal (like when u were installing but u won't install)
2. then it will open the application, press on "configure".
3. press create desktop entry :D

Comment: this one surely worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

May be I'm too late by anyways. 
Idea 19.1 is creating entry which is in the file jetbrains-idea.desktop. when I hit launcher and try to find via typing `idea` it's not showing. Once I've made a copy of a file:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop /usr/share/applications/idea.desktop
```

it has started showing.