# After installation, Netbeans 10.0 won't run from Ubuntu 18.04 desktop

Tags: 18.04, jdk, netbeans

I have Netbeans 10.0 installed on Ubuntu 18.04 in the `/opt/netbeans` directory.

Netbeans 10.0 was installed just by extracting from zip file `incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin.zip` downloaded using the command:

```
sudo wget http://mirrors.wuchna.com/apachemirror/incubator/netbeans/incubating-netbeans/incubating-10.0/incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin.zip
```

After extraction you will find `netbeans` folder under `/opt` directory. Issue the following extract command:

```
sudo unzip ~/Downloads/incubating-netbeans-10.0-bin.zip -d /opt/
```

After Netbeans extracted into `/opt/netbeans` directory, a shortcut file `netbeans.desktop` was created, edited and then installed at `/usr/share/applications/` directory by the following command:

```
sudo desktop-file-install netbeans.desktop
```

The contents of `netbeans.desktop` is:

[image: Contents of netbeans.desktop]

The installed Java version  on the desktop is JDK11

[image: Java HOME]

I have put Netbeans binary on PATH by running `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/netbeans/bin` using `~/.bashrc` script file

[image: Netbeans PATH]

1. When I click on the Netbeans icon on my desktop, there is just a flicker and the IDE never appeared and nothing happened

   [image: Netbeans Icon]
2. Nevertheless, when I run `netbeans` in a terminal, I get the following output

   [image: Netbeans Running]

   ```
   WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
   WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue (jar:file:/opt/netbeans/platform/modules/org-netbeans-swing-plaf.jar!/) to method javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.getColorForState(javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthContext,javax.swing.plaf.synth.ColorType)
   WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.netbeans.swing.plaf.gtk.ThemeValue
   WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
   WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
   ```

Can somebody be kind enough to throw some light on this issue? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the value of `Exec` in the desktop entry a.k.a. the "shortcut" contains an error. According to [Desktop Entry Specification](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

> The Exec key must contain a command line. A command line consists of an executable program optionally followed by one or more arguments. The executable program can either be specified with its full path or with the name of the executable only. If no full path is provided the executable is looked up in the $PATH environment variable used by the desktop environment. The name or path of the executable program may not contain the equal sign ("=").

Also, `UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` looks like a user-defined variable which doesn't work in Desktop Entries. So, better remove that and provide the absolute path of NetBeans, i.e.,

```bsh
Exec=env /opt/netbeans/bin/netbeans #You can also omit "env"
```

Answer (score 1):

NetBeans has been recently updated to version 10.0 in the default Ubuntu 18.04-20.04 repositories. This version is compatible with openjdk-11-jdk out of the box. To install both packages in Ubuntu 18.04-20.04 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install netbeans openjdk-11-jdk
```

This is the most convenient way to install NetBeans because there are also several NetBeans support libraries in the default Ubuntu repositories. You can list these packages with the following command:

```
apt search netbeans
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention @karel