# Ubuntu 16.04: How do I add/remove pinned apps to Unity Launcher via terminal?

Tags: unity, 16.04, launcher

so I've searched the net on my topic but I didn't find any answer.

Is it possible? If yes, can you please tell me? Thanks :)

Comment: It is possible but requires a script. I'll write one once I'm free today. It's not too complex.

Comment: @Serg thank you so much. I'm moving my setup from OSX to Ubuntu. On OS X, I have a bash script that sets up my MacPro to exactly how I want it. Just trying to do the same on Ubuntu.

Comment: Is it alright if I use Python ? it's a bit easier to do it in Python than bash.

Comment: @Serg feel free to use whatever you want to use. thanks again :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Contents:

1. General theory of Launcher operation
2. Possible ways of removing and appending to Unity launcher
3. launcherctl.py utility

#### 1. General theory of launcher operation

The Unity launcher essentially is a list of `.desktop` files. They are essentially shortcuts that allow launching applications as well as performing custom actions. Typically they are stored in `/usr/share/applications` , but can be also located in `~/.local/share/applications`, and anywhere else on the system. For the general case, I recommend storing such files in `/usr/share/applications` for all users or `~/.local/share/applications` for each individual user.

The `Dconf` database of settings allows storing list of such apps for Unity launcher and can be viewed and altered with `gsettings` utility. For instance:

```
$ gsettings get  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
['application://wps-office-et.desktop', 'application://wps-office-wpp.desktop', 'application://wps-office-wps.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
$ gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites  "['wechat.desktop']"                                                         
$ gsettings get  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites                                                                               
['application://wechat.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
```

As you can see all the `.desktop` files have `application://` prefix on them, however it is not required when setting the launcher list. The items with `unity://` prefix are not alterable and cannot be removed.

The `gsettings get  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` and `gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites` commands can be used to create functions in your `~/.bashrc` , for instance:

```
get_launcher()
{
    gsettings get  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
}

set_launcher()
{
    # call this as set_launcher "['file1.desktop','file2.desktop']"
    gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$1"
}
```

Example:

```
$ set_launcher "['firefox.desktop','gnome-terminal.desktop']"                                                                         
$ get_launcher                                                                                                                        
['application://firefox.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
```

#### 2. Possible ways of removing and appending to Unity Launcher

The simplest example has already been shown - via `gsettings` utility. Removing and appending specific item requires parsing the `gsettings` output. This can be done via `sed` or `awk` utilities , and with effort even in `bash`. However, I find that python allows the easier approach and "path of least resistance". Thus, the examples provided here use `gsettings` jointly with python.

Here's a case of removal:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites|                                                                               
> python -c 'import ast,sys; x =[]; x = [i for l in sys.stdin for i in ast.literal_eval(l)]; 
> x.pop(x.index("application://"+sys.argv[1])); print x' firefox.desktop
['application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices']
```

What is happening here ? We pass output of the `gsettings get` via pipe to python. Python then reads standard input stream and using `ast` library evaluates the text representation of the list, and converts it to actual list that python can recognize. This greatly simplifies the work - if this was awk or sed we would have to deal with removing and appending individual characters. Finally , we remove ( pop ) the second command-line argument ( indicated by `sys.argv[1]` ) by finding it's index in the list. We now have new list, which can be passed on further via pipe to `gsettings set`

The complete command is then this:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites|
> python -c 'import ast,sys; x =[]; x = [i for l in sys.stdin for i in ast.literal_eval(l)]; 
> x.pop(x.index("application://"+sys.argv[1])); print "\""+repr(x)+"\""' firefox.desktop |
> xargs -I {} gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites {}
```

Which can be nicely put into a `~/.bashrc` function like so:

```
remove_launcher_item()
{
  gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites|
  python -c 'import ast,sys; x =[]; x = [i for l in sys.stdin for i in ast.literal_eval(l)];\
  x.pop(x.index("application://"+sys.argv[1])); print "\""+repr(x)+"\""' "$1" |
  xargs -I {} gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites {}
}
```

A few things to note here is that we need to print again "string" representation of list enclosed into quotes and pass it via `xargs`. The idea with appending is similar, except instead of `pop` we use `append` function:

```
append_launcher_item()
{
  gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites|
  python -c 'import ast,sys; x =[]; x = [i for l in sys.stdin for i in ast.literal_eval(l)];\
  x.append("application://"+sys.argv[1]); print "\""+repr(x)+"\""' "$1" |
  xargs -I {} gsettings set  com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites {}

}
```

Sample run:

```
$ get_launcher                                                                                                                        
['unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices', 'application://firefox.desktop']
$ append_launcher_item gnome-terminal.desktop                                                                                         
$ get_launcher                                                                                                                        
['unity://running-apps', 'unity://devices', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop']
$
```

These functions don't necessarily have to be part of `~/.bashrc`. You can place them into a script as well

#### 3. launcherctl.py utility

Over time, I've researched and build a set of functions in python that can effectively do the same as `gsettings` utility. Putting the power of python together with those functions, I've made `launcherctl.py` utility.

This is a work in progress and will be expanded to include more functions in future. For this specific question, I will leave the source code as it appears in first version. Further versions and improvements can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/launcherctl.py).

What are the advantages of this script compared to bash functions ? 
1. This is a "centralized" utility with specific purpose. You don't have to have separate script/function for each action. 
2. Simple to use, minimalist command-line options
3. When used in conjunction with other utilities, this provides for more readable code.

**Usage**:

As shown by the `-h` command line option:

```
$ ./launcherctl.py -h                                                                                                                 
usage: launcherctl.py [-h] [-f FILE] [-a] [-r] [-l] [-c]

Copyright 2016. Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy.
    This command line utility allows appending and removing items
    from Unity launcher, as well as listing and clearing the
    Launcher items.

    --file option is required for --append and --remove 


optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE, --file FILE
  -a, --append
  -r, --remove
  -l, --list
  -c, --clear
```

Command line usage is simple.

Appending:

```
$ ./launcherctl.py -a -f wechat.desktop
```

Removal:

```
$ ./launcherctl.py -r -f wechat.desktop
```

Clearing launcher completely:

```
$ ./launcherctl.py -c
```

Listing items on the launcher:

```
$ ./launcherctl.py -l                                                                                                                 
chromium-browser.desktop
firefox.desktop
opera.desktop
vivaldi-beta.desktop
```

As mentioned before, it can be used with other commands. For instance,adding from file:

```
$ cat new_list.txt                                                                                                                    
firefox.desktop
wechat.desktop
gnome-terminal.desktop    
$ cat new_list.txt | xargs -L 1 launcherctl.py -a -f
```

Same can be used with removal of items given from a text file

Removing a 3rd item from the `dash` button:

```
$ launcherctl.py  -l | awk 'NR==3' | xargs -L 1 launcherctl.py -r -f
```

**Obtaining source code and installation**

Manual way:

1. Create a directory `~/bin`.
2. Save source code from below into file `~/bin/launcherctl.py`
3. If you are `bash` user, you can source `~/.profile`, or logout and login. The `~/bin` directory will be added to your `$PATH` variable automatically. For those who don't use `bash` , add `~/bin` to your `$PATH` variable inside your shell configuration file, like so: `PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin`

As I've mentioned latest changes to the code go into the GitHub repository.  If you have `git` installed, the steps are simpler:

1. `git clone https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep.git ~/bin/sergrep`
2. `echo "PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin/sergrep" >> ~/.bashrc`
3. `source ~/.bashrc`. After this step, you can call `launcherctl.py` as any other command. Getting updates is as simple as `cd ~/bin/sergrep;git pull`

Obtaining code from GitHub without `git`:

1. `cd /tmp`
2. `wget https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/archive/master.zip`
3. `unzip master.zip`
4. If you don't have `~/bin` , make it with `mkdir ~/bin`
5. `mv sergrep-master/launcherctl.py ~/bin/launcherctl.py`

In all cases, the same rules apply - the script must live in a directory that is added to `PATH` variable and must have executable permissions set with `chmod +x launcherctl.py`

---

**Original source code**:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
# Author: Serg Kolo , contact: 1047481448@qq.com
# Date: Sept 24, 2016
# Purpose: command-line utility for controling the launcher
#          settings
# Tested on: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
#
#
# Licensed under The MIT License (MIT).
# See included LICENSE file or the notice below.
#
# Copyright © 2016 Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included
# in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
# SOFTWARE.

import gi
from gi.repository import Gio
import argparse
import sys

def gsettings_get(schema, path, key):
    """Get value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    return gsettings.get_value(key)

def gsettings_set(schema, path, key, value):
    """Set value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema, path)
    if isinstance(value,list ):
        return gsettings.set_strv(key, value)
    if isinstance(value,int):
        return gsettings.set_int(key, value)

def puts_error(string):
    sys.stderr.write(string+"\n")
    sys.exit(1)

def list_items():
    """ lists all applications pinned to launcher """
    schema = 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher'
    path = None
    key = 'favorites'
    items = list(gsettings_get(schema,path,key))
    for item in items:
        if 'application://' in item:
            print(item.replace("application://","").lstrip())

def append_item(item):
    """ appends specific item to launcher """
    schema = 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher'
    path = None
    key = 'favorites'
    items = list(gsettings_get(schema,path,key))

    if not item.endswith(".desktop"):
        puts_error( ">>> Bad file.Must have .desktop extension!!!")

    items.append('application://' + item)
    gsettings_set(schema,path,key,items)

def remove_item(item):
    """ removes specific item from launcher """
    schema = 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher'
    path = None
    key = 'favorites'
    items = list(gsettings_get(schema,path,key))

    if not item.endswith(".desktop"):
       puts_error(">>> Bad file. Must have .desktop extension!!!")
    items.pop(items.index('application://'+item))
    gsettings_set(schema,path,key,items)

def clear_all():
    """ clears the launcher completely """
    schema = 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher'
    path = None
    key = 'favorites'

    gsettings_set(schema,path,key,[])

def parse_args():
    """parse command line arguments"""

    info="""Copyright 2016. Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy.
    This command line utility allows appending and removing items
    from Unity launcher, as well as listing and clearing the
    Launcher items.

    --file option is required for --append and --remove 
    """
    arg_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
                 description=info,
                 formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-f','--file',action='store',
                            type=str,required=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-a','--append',
                            action='store_true',required=False)

    arg_parser.add_argument('-r','--remove',
                            action='store_true',required=False)
    arg_parser.add_argument('-l','--list',
                            action='store_true',required=False)

    arg_parser.add_argument('-c','--clear',
                            action='store_true',required=False)
    return arg_parser.parse_args()

def main():
    """ Defines program entry point """
    args = parse_args()

    if args.list:
       list_items()
       sys.exit(0)

    if args.append:
       if not args.file:
          puts_error(">>>Specify .desktop file with --file option")

       append_item(args.file)
       sys.exit(0)

    if args.remove:
       if not args.file:
          puts_error(">>>Specify .desktop file with --file option")

       remove_item(args.file)
       sys.exit(0)

    if args.clear:
       clear_all()
       sys.exit(0)

    sys.exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

#### Additional notes:

- in the past I've created an answer that allows setting the launcher list from file: https://askubuntu.com/a/761021/295286
- I've also created a Unity indicator for switching between multiple lists. See instructions here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/launcher-list-indicator-update-ppa-workspaces

Comment: very impressed. most comprehensive answer I've gotten ever. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

To change pinned apps via terminal for the GNOME desktop manager,

Get list of current pinned apps:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps
```

> ['firefox.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop']

Append app (eg. Sublime-Text) to dock:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell favorite-apps \
"['firefox.desktop','org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop',\
'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop','sublime-text_subl.desktop']"
```