# Copy Unity Launchers from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, launcher, copy

Trying to recover a bunch of `.desktop` files from Ubuntu <kbd>**14.04**</kbd> copied to <kbd>**16.04**</kbd>, but they don't appear in the Launcher.

Did the following (`/14.04` is mounted to the old Ubuntu disk / FS)

```
cd ~/.local/share/applications
cp -pr /14.04/home/ring0/.local/share/applications/[bunch-of].desktop .
```

but they do no appear after logging back to <kbd>**16.04**</kbd>. (same user / uid on both versions)

Had a look at `/usr/share/applications`, but the files are in the `.local` dir.

Looking at the structure of the `.desktop` files on both versions, they look similar.

Anything else to check / setup?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean they don't appear in the launcher or n Dash?

Comment: In the launcher

Comment: @ringø just a question: Did you try dragging them to the launcher, or did you just put them into `~/.local/shared/applications/` ? Also, are you using Unity desktop ? Or something else ?

Comment: @Serg No I didn't try to drag them yet - will probably do that stuff during the coming week end.

Comment: @ringø Well there's your problem. Just because you drop `.desktop` files into folder they won't appear on the launcher.  Drag them, they will appear on the launcher. Also consider using one of the methods in my other answer that i linked  in point 3 of my answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to manually add it to Unity Launcher, it's not enough to just put it in the folder.

1. browse to your `.local/share/applications` folder in Nautilus (the folder might be hidden, so you might need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. drag `.desktop` files from Nautilus to Unity Launcher, it should then appear instantly

Comment: most logical & straightforward answer of the current bunch.

Comment: +1 This has been tested working in Ubuntu 16.04 and the added `.desktop` file a.k.a. shortcut in Unity Launcher persists after reboot.

Answer (score 3):

You have to add them to launcher favorites list. To read current list:

```
~$ dconf read /com/canonical/unity/launcher/favorites
['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']
```

To write new list

```
dconf write /com/canonical/unity/launcher/favorites "['application://nautilus.desktop', 'application://firefox.desktop', 'application://libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'application://unity-control-center.desktop', 'application://gnome-terminal.desktop', 'unity://running-apps', 'unity://expo-icon', 'unity://devices']"
```

Not sure if possible to read `dconf` db of 14.04 using `chroot`, If your 14.04 still boot-able, boot it then use `dconf read ...` to get the list. Otherwise, write the list manually from `ls ~/.local/share/applications`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the *.desktop files have execution permission?
I copied once (with -p option) on 16.04 from /usr/share/applications/ to ~/.local/share/applications/. The files lost execution permission. I guess this is a similar situation.

Comment: Reading the question more closely, you'll see that the copy is from `/14.04/home/ring0/.local/share/applications/[bunch-of].desktop` to `~/.local/share/applications` (where `~` is ring0). Anyway checked the ACL to be sure, and they're correct.

Comment: For the launcher, being executable is irrellevant.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Nope. If `.desktop` files are located anywhere in user's folder , which is also `~/.local/share/applications/` , they do need executable permissions to both run AND be placed onto launcher. This adheres to Ubuntu's security policy.  I've tested it also. Launcher with no exec permissions cannot be placed onto launcher

Comment: @Serg, really, but no. None of my launchers in `~/.local/share/applications` is executable. Has never been different. What are you running?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Please read https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies  I don't know what's wrong with your Ubuntu, but that's how all Ubuntu versions work. If you want , I can provide quotes from other AU answers. Only items placed in `/usr/share/application` don't require executable bit set. User's folder's do require that bit set

Comment: @Serg please see this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1155139/noexec.png I believe my eyes rather than what I read. Has never been differently since I wrote the Quicklist Editor for 11.04.

Comment: @Serg only when used as *double-click launcher* it needs to be executable.

Comment: @JacobVlijm you didn't show Permissions tab, which is where actual execution is set. See: http://imgur.com/a/1IRY6  To be placed on the launcher and allow user to run that application, it needs to be executable.  Otherwise, Unity flags application as untrusted. It has nothing to do with double clicking, but with letting .desktop run, of which double click is only one way. Sorry, but i have no time for this discussion

Comment: @Serg The Unity Quicklist Editor https://launchpad.net/~vlijm/+archive/ubuntu/qle is based on those launchers *not* being executables (simply copied from `~/usr/share/applications`). I believe something like 15.000 downloads without a single bug file on that. You should conclude from the generic icon that the launcher is not executable, but for the record, look again into the link to my dropbox. You must have done something adventurous if it works differently on your system.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Well, I'm not familiar with The Quicklist Editor, so I cannot point out what might be the cause. Besides, we're dealing with `.desktop` files themselves. Your application is non-standard.  As for executable bit, it is something Ubuntu's official security policy requires and there are hundreds of questions relating to "Why does my .desktop file not running?" , and to all of them the solution is the same.

Comment: Again, that is for *double-click*.  *" Sorry, but i have no time for this discussion"*?? You started it. The fact that the application is non-standard is totally irrelevant. Not a single bug on this subject *is* relevant.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  Double click is just but one method of running .desktop file.

Comment: @Serg Please pick any non-executable launcher in `/usr/share/applications` does it call the application? No. There is an essential difference in how the `.desktop` file is used, in the launcher or on double-click.

Comment: @JacobVlijm  "Does it call the application?" It does. And please enlighten me on the difference between launcher and double click. Aside from having right click options, their purpose is the same. Plus again, in all my experience , from 13.10 to 16.04 all Ubuntu versions work exactly same, and require x bit on .desktop files.

Comment: @Serg, let's not make it a quarrel, let's say you are absolutely sure they do need to be executable to run from the launcher, I am absolutely sure they don't. Only when used as double-click launcher from e.g. your Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Current answers provide bits and pieces of the proper approach. In this answer, I would like to provide more coherent overview of what needs to be done to port the `.desktop` files.

1. Actual applications will have to be installed on the new system. `.desktop` files are merely shortcuts for those applications. If the actual application is not installed, it is pointless to copy `.desktop` files.
2. As per Ubuntu's security policy, (link https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/Policies) , the `.desktop` files residing in user's home folder have to have executable bit set in order to run (also discussed on another Ask Ubuntu question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/419657/295286)). <s>Quick test confirms that they **do not** stick to launcher, unless executable bit is set.</s> Without executable bit set, they will not run and Unity will [deem such application launcher as untrusted](https://askubuntu.com/q/10395/295286). <s>(Note that if the `.desktop` is cached in memory, it can still appear on the launcher when you remove executable permission - don't be fooled by that).</s> Use `chmod +x file.desktop` in terminal or right-clicking on application and 
   under Permissions tab check "Allow executing as program" option.

   Another potential issue is ownership and read permissions. If the file belongs to different user and groups, without read permissions you cannot access `.desktop` file, thus it won't launch and won't still to Unity Launcher. The solution here is to either `sudo chmod +r name.desktop` or `chown $USER:$USER name.desktop`.

   **NOTE**: I've put strikethrough over parts that turned out to be incorrect. For a very peculiar reason, Unity launcher deviates from the security policy.
3. Placing `.desktop` files into `~/.local/share/applications` (as has been revealed in the comments) doesn't make them appear on Unity launcher. That folder is for storing your own, custom `.desktop` files. Adding items to Unity launcher can be done by hand, or via command
   line with `gsetting` or `dconf` command. There are alternative
   approaches, however. Please see this post on multiple ways of adding
   `.desktop` files to the Launcher:
   https://askubuntu.com/a/829228/295286

Comment: #2 is pretty much completely incorrect (- except for ownership part though again the x is not needed in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: @doug I've put strikethough incorrect parts. The fact that you need executable bit set for double-clicking is true - there's literally tons of questions on askubuntu about "why does my .desktop file not running?" and 90% of the time it's the executable bit.  Check the links I've provided

Comment: D. clicking, yes, but the question was about use via the (unity) launcher. Also, on 2nd thought ownership probably is also irrelevant in ~/.local/share/applications

Comment: @doug  my original assumption was that security policy also extends to Unity launcher, which it turned out to be false. In my tests , I've had a few launchers which just wouldn't stick, which I still can't have explanation.  As for ownership,well, try it out for yourself: `chmod root:root` one of the `.desktop` files and see if if sticks to the Unity Launcher. I test my answers, so i know ownership affects it.

Comment: @doug  let me add correction to that:  if file belongs to a different user:group , and you (or your group) don't have read permissions over that file, then it won't work. If file is `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root` (so , read permission granted to all)  , then it can stick to the launcher