# Adding a program to the launcher with a script

Tags: command-line, unity, bash, scripts, launcher

I'm writing a bash script that modifies a program, then adds an icon to the unity launcher. Although I've created the .desktop file in /usr/share/applications, I can't see a way to programmatically add the shortcut to the launcher.

Comment: see also  http://askubuntu.com/a/761021/295286   or   http://askubuntu.com/a/829228/295286

Answer (score 4):

- First get the list of applications from the launcher:

```
$ gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites
```

- Make an array of the items.
- Then have your install script add your application to the array
- Then have your script add the items from the created array to this command with item comma separated:

```
$ gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['app1','app2','app3','your program.desktop']"
```

The **app#** is the applications from the array that you are including in your installer script.

Replace **your program** with the name of the `*.desktop` launcher you created.

Update:
The procedure is listed above.

**This is a command line that will append your application to the launcher**

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "$(gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites | sed "s/]/,'Your Program.desktop']/")"
```

Add the above commandline to your install script.  Replace the bold **Your Program.desktop** with the program you created.  This will not clobber what your current icons.  It'll append.

Comment: `No such key 'favourites'`

Comment: You have that error because there isn't a key `favourites`.  I understand dependent on the language dialect there's a difference in spelling.  But the required keyname in Ubuntu is `favorites`.  Try copying and pasting the command.  Then change only what is highlighted in bold.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're saying about adding one... Are you saying adding an Icon for the desktop launcher, or are you saying adding an icon to the Ubuntu Launcher.  The command adds a created desktop launcher, which the user has created and placed in his applications folder, to  Ubuntu's side bar launcher.  It won't affect the icon.  Whatever icon is already included in the *.desktop file the user has create, will app in the launcher.  The user call manually right click and stick a applicaton to the launcher.  This command will allow the OP's installer script to do this.

Comment: Simply: `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher favorites "['your program.desktop']"` *sets* the launcher to `"['your program.desktop']"`. It removes all other icons, which definitely is not the intention of OP. Did you try the command?

Comment: Now I see what you are saying... Thanks.  I'll fix the answer.  Your refernce to single icon to the launcher.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53749/discussion-between-l-d-james-and-jacob-vlijm).

Comment: @L.D.James I get it now, sorry that was a really silly error. Can I create an array variable and add my app to it programmatically? Or do I have to take everything out of the array, add my app to them, and create a new array?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write the script yet.  I'll write a crude example and post it ASAP.    But the gist is to first grab all the items that are there with the **get** argument.  Place them in an array and include your desktop item in the array, then read the array into the "[]" field with entries comma separated.